# Using Vanilla JS to add inline CSS property and fallback value

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari

The problem I am trying to solve is basically the issue with Safari iOs and Vh calculations.

Here is the function:

```
  function overflowHandler() {
    const header = document.querySelector('.header-container').getBoundingClientRect().height;
    const regionTop = document.querySelector('.region-top').getBoundingClientRect().height;
    const totalHeaderHeight = header + regionTop;
    if (window.innerWidth < 1080) {
      flyout.style.height = 'calc(100vh - ' + totalHeaderHeight + 'px)';
    }
  }
```

But I need to be able to also pass in `height: webkit-fill-available` as a style as well to fix the bug on iOS where the user can't scroll completely to the bottom of the nav.

I've tried using `element.style.cssText` to set both height properties, but whatever is the rightmost value is what gets rendered in the browser.

Example of what I mean would be:

```
element.style.cssText = 'height: calc(100vh - ' + totalHeaderHeight + 'px); height: -webkit-fill-available;'
```

would render as `height: -webkit-fill-available;`

I am at a loss on any other way to make it work or how else to ensure the full height of the menu can be scrolled on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Use `element.setAttribute('style', 'height: -webkit-fill-available;')`